# How to implement json to android correct?

Tags: android, json

I've been following a tutorial on how to show a Json arrays on android and I constantly get "Couldn't get json from server. Check internet connection!" and I can't figure out why. My Json is being generated from a php file and this works when I'm creating a list on my browser. So I'm sure my Json works.

EDIT: What adjustments do I have to do to be able to get a read from this url?

JSON array from "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=bond"

Android:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity{

private ListView lv;
private ProgressDialog progress;

private String url="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=bond";

ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> booklist;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    booklist=new ArrayList<>();
    lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    new getBooks().execute();
}

public class getBooks extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
    progress=new ProgressDialog(HomeScreen.this);
    progress.setMessage("Fetching JSON.,.");
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();
}
protected Void doInBackground(Void...arg0){
    HTTP_Handler hh = new HTTP_Handler();
    String jString = hh.makeHTTPCall(url);

    if (jString != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jString);
            JSONArray books = jObj.getJSONArray("bookinfo");
            for (int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject book = books.getJSONObject(i);

                String name=book.getString("name");
                String author=book.getString("author");


                HashMap<String, String> bookdata = new HashMap<>();


                bookdata.put("name", name);
                bookdata.put("author", author);


                booklist.add(bookdata);
            }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }
    } else {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check internet connection!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Void Result){
    super.onPostExecute(Result);
    if(progress.isShowing()){
        progress.dismiss();
    }
    ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(
            HomeScreen.this,
            booklist,
            R.layout.bucket_list,
            new String[]{"name","author"},
            new int[]{R.id.list_Name,R.id.list_author);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your browser have to authenticate against 'website/filename.php' to return JSON? I don't see any authentication steps going on in your code. If your code is freely available, this is probably not the issue. At first glance it appears that since now JSON is being returned from the server that this could be an issue.

Comment: No, there is no authentication